# Angularjs token decode

Tags: angularjs, authorization, token

I am doing a token based authentication for the user using angularjs and webapi.
I can see the token generated in the browser console as this. How can I decode this token to get user details like role and name ?.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to use https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt in your project.

You need to inject angular-jwt into your app and you can do the following:

```
angular
  .module('app', ['angular-jwt'])
  .controller('Controller', function Controller(jwtHelper) {
      var token = //your token
      var decodedToken = jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
  });
```